# Bootstrap popover is not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

http://www.rightoption.co/

You will find "Our Client" On RHS side of page, Click on thumbnails it opens popover(Firefox),
But it's not working in Google chrome, Please help me out of this

**Edit** : Website is no longer on hosting

Comment: Your `href="#"` si making the page scroll back to the top every time you click on a popover. If you want to prevent that you should use `event.preventDefault()` in your `click` bindings.

Comment: the code isnt present on url now, Website is updated

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This is because the default trigger for the popover is focus.  In Firefox, when you click on something, it seems to gain focus but that does not seem to be true for Chrome in this case.

You can try one of 2 things:

Try to manually set the trigger on the  tag to be "manual".  So add this attribute data-trigger="manual"

OR

In your document onload, instead of doing:

```
$('#element, #element1').popover('toggle').popover('hide');
```

use this line instead:

```
$('#element, #element1')
   .popover()
   .click(function(e) { 
       e.preventDefault(); 
       $(this).focus(); 
   });
```

Comment: data-trigger="manual" is not working for me, But $('#element, #element1')
   .popover()
   .click(function(e) { 
       e.preventDefault(); 
       $(this).focus(); 
   }); This works me , thnx

Comment: Neither for me, but the last option works perfect. Thanks a lot

Comment: This worked, but it caused popup to open twice on Firefox. Even-though it was not noticeable, this below thread has a permanent solution... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25042697/bootstraps-popover-only-working-on-buttons-not-anchors-or-spans

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer is pretty dated now, but it came up for me in a Google search, so I would like to add that as of version 2.3.0 Bootstrap now allows to send 'hover focus' as the trigger so it will work on both.  And very importantly, it also allows a 'click' trigger that works as you'd expect (specifically for Chrome).

Comment: "hover focus" does not work for me in FF using 2.3.2.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me!

```
var el = $('[data-toggle="popover"]');
el
    .on('shown.bs.popover', function(){
        $(document).on('click.popover', function() {
            el.popover('hide');
            $(document).off('click.popover');
        });                            
    })
    .popover();
```

**Update**: The above had an issue whereby clicking another popover element while a popover is displayed closes the open popover but doesn't open the new one. The following will close the open popover AND open the new one with one click.

```
var el = $('[data-toggle="popover"]');
el
    .on('click', function(e){
        var el = $(this);
        setTimeout(function(){
            el.popover('show');
        }, 200); // Must occur after document click event below.
    })
    .on('shown.bs.popover', function(){
        $(document).on('click.popover', function() {
            el.popover('hide'); // Hides all 
        });
    })
    .on('hide.bs.popover', function(){
        $(document).off('click.popover');
    });
```