# Bootstrap's popover only working on buttons - not anchors or spans

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I am including tooltip.js and popover.js.

When my markup looks like so:

```
<button class="popover-dismiss" data-toggle="popover" title="sheen" 
data-content="&lt;a href=&quot;sheen60&quot;&gt;60&lt;/a&gt;, &lt;a href=&quot;sheen80&quot;&gt;80&lt;/a&gt;">
PDS
</button>
```

with JS

```
$('.popover-dismiss').popover({
  trigger: 'focus',
  html: 'true'
})
```

Then everything works fine. However, when I change my `button` to an `a`, it breaks. There are no errors in the console. It just simply does not give the popup.

```
<a href="javascript://" class="popover-dismiss" data-toggle="popover" title="sheen" 
data-content="&lt;a href=&quot;sheen60&quot;&gt;60&lt;/a&gt;, &lt;a href=&quot;sheen80&quot;&gt;80&lt;/a&gt;">
PDS
</a>
```

The exact same attributes. Just an anchor instead of a button. I have also tried using a span and that does not appear to work either.

Comment: I'm having no problems.. http://codepen.io/pattmorter/pen/vueAm

Comment: Well... that's weird. You caused me to dig in to it a bit more. In Chrome my page and your pen both have a working button and a broken link.

In Firefox, my page and your pen both have a broken button and a working link...

Comment: Interesting indeed... I'm using Firefox.

Comment: You're using firefox and both work for you?

Comment: Yup. Worked perfectly fine.

Comment: If you remove `href="javascript://"` from the `<a>` it stops working.

Comment: Having the same problem. This happens when trigger is set to `focus`. Have yet to dig into the code to find out why.

Comment: @Stanley if you came here via google hoping for a solution, please check out my self-answer below and let me know if it worked for you.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Ok so it turns out there is a bug in Twitter Bootstrap. It has been opened and closed a couple times.

There is currently a work around:

1) Do not use `trigger: focus` when initializing bootstrap popovers
2) Instead use `data-trigger="focus"` as an attribute to the items which will trigger the popover
3) Items which have a popover will need to have `tabindex="-1"` explicitly declared.

Cross-browser working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/v5L7m/3/

I have also confirmed this in a real-world use case scenario.

**Edit:** @xanderiel noted that `tabindex=0` now appears to cause a browser native focus border which is what my original answer called for. They say a tabindex of `-1` eliminates this border.

Comment: Only the strict compliance of this three advises made it work for me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: It seems like at least the tabindex="0" is no longer required after upgrading to Bootstrap Nuget package > 3.2.0

Comment: I had to additionally add `href="#"` because my `a` previously lacked one.

Comment: Using this with bootstrap 3.3.5

Comment: Saved lot's of time and tried lot's of failed attempts. This worked like a charm. Seems `tabindex=0` is performing a vital role here!

Comment: Perfect Solution, Thanks saved lot more time.

Comment: Using Bootstrap 3.3.7. Using tabindex=0 worked for me.

Comment: Thanks, still an issue in Bootstrap 4. Had to do all of the above to fix it – great advice. `tabindex=-1` works as well for me – `tabindex=0` draws that ugly focus border around your element when the popover is visible.

Answer (score 8):

Well, I guess that if you want to use "focus" as a trigger your element must be focusable.  Setting tabindex forces the element to be focusable, that's why trigger "focus" starts working when tabindex is set.

Consider using a tabindex of -1 if you do not expect users to actually stop on the element hitting the tab key.

That's all there is to it. Trigger: focus can be used in JS initialization.

Answer (score 7):

There's no need for a workaround or anything. It works just fine if you set the info via JS, here's an example:

**HTML:**

```
<a tabindex="0" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" role="button" data-toggle="popover" title="Dismissible popover" data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. Right?">Dismissible popover</a>
```

**JS:**

```
$(function() {
    $(document).popover({
        selector: '[data-toggle=popover]',
        trigger: 'focus'
    });
});
```

**JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/s02ykLo2/

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `container: 'body'` option for `popover()` call.

Comment: Setting `container: 'body'` doesn't help