# How to close a popover on click outside in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to close the popover if the user click outside the popover. in the below code .tried it with few examples that were posted for clicking outside the popover but not working.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <link  rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.22/angular.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div class="example" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <a class="btn btn-lg btn-success" href="javascript:;" popover ng-click="click()">popover</a>
        <div style="display:none">
            <div class="pop-content" id="val">
                {{ myVar }}
                <input type="button" />
            </div>
        </div>
      
        <input ng-model="myVar">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
<script>
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
    myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
        $scope.myVar = 3 + 4;   
    }) 
    myApp.directive('popover', function ($compile) {
        return {
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                // define popover for this element
                $(element).popover({
                    html: true,
                    placement: "top",
                    // grab popover content from the next element
                    content: $compile($(element).siblings(".pop-content").contents())(scope)
                });
            }
        }
    });

</script>
```

Comment: I tried running your code. Was going to try to attach an blur event handler but this code does not do anything.  Can you put it in jsfiddle or something.

Comment: I have taken the example from this link only  http://jsfiddle.net/fScua/766/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you ran into a Twitter bootstrap bug.. see this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25042697/bootstraps-popover-only-working-on-buttons-not-anchors-or-spans)

you need to change you html to allow this feature.

```
<a class="btn btn-lg btn-success" href="javascript:;" popover ng-click="click()">popover</a>
```

to

```
<a popover class="btn btn-lg btn-success" href="javascript:;" tabindex="0" data-trigger="focus" >popover</a>
```

another problem is that you're not providing the `content` in JavaScript properly.

```
$(element).siblings("div").children(".pop-content").contents()
```

I did this inside you link function.

here is the [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/kOM1tljHHySBSOnyq2Qe?p=preview)

## Note: now you can't close it with the anchor itself..

## -----------Update----------

To achieve this you'll have to do something like this `data-trigger="click focus"`, but by using this I am running into an unusual bug. on first click the popover flick opens and closes immediately..